# i want to do a dynamic form with v-if

Tags: forms, vue.js, element-ui

I want to display an additional input if the person clicks yes and clicks on nothing

i try to do that with v-if but i the value never change
this is the entire page in vuejs maybe i need to do a method, i already try without quote and with, i to set value like club = 1 but didn't work to. 
I'm not sure if my v-bind is good too

```
        <el-form-item label="Possédez vous un club ?">
          <el-radio-group v-model="ruleForm.club">
            <el-radio label="Oui" v-bind:value="true"></el-radio>
            <el-radio label="Non" v-bind:value="false"></el-radio>
          </el-radio-group>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item v-if="'ruleForm.club' == true" label="Nom du club" prop="nClub">
          <el-input v-model="ruleForm.nClub" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
          <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('ruleForm')">Submit</el-button>
        <el-button @click="resetForm('ruleForm')">Reset</el-button>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    var validatePseudo = (rule, value, callback) => {
      if (value === '' || value !== 'coach') {
        callback(new Error('Please input the pseudo'))
      } else {
        callback()
      }
    }
    var validatePass = (rule, value, callback) => {
      if (value === '' || value !== 'password') {
        callback(new Error('Please input the password'))
      } else {
        callback()
      }
    }
    return {
      ruleForm: {
        nom: '',
        prenom: '',
        pseudo: '',
        email: '',
        pass: '',
        statue: '',
        club: '',
        nClub: ''
      },
      rules: {
        pseudo: [
          { validator: validatePseudo, trigger: 'blur' }
        ],
        pass: [
          { validator: validatePass, trigger: 'blur' }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm (formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
          this.$router.push({
            name: '/'
          })
        } else {
          console.log('error submit!!')
          return false
        }
      })
    },
    resetForm (formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].resetFields()
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to remove `''` (quotes) from `v-if="'ruleForm.club' == true"`

Comment: that didn't change anything

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: did your try only `v-if="ruleForm.club"`

Comment: First check the data is changing or not , also you can use v-show instead of v-if

Comment: when i try v-if="ruleForm.club" that work but for both ( if i click on yes that show the form and no same ) how i just take the yes ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your question, but from what I can tell you would like to add an inputfield if a user selects a certain radio button using `v-if`. I've recreated this in a jsfiddle. Is this wat your looking for?

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Mertakus/8wx4h7up/3/